# How to use some of needed parameters in java code when I am making a request a web service method

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl

I'm was ganerate java code using eclipse option "Generate Client" on wsdl file.
After that, I'm trying to create a request to the Web server using generated code.
But in this step there is a small problem: request needed 4 parameters, which 2 parameters are optional. If set values of theese parameters to NULL, I get an error.
If it simply, request has this format:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://ossj.org/xml/Inventory/v1-2" xmlns:v11="http://ossj.org/xml/Common/v1-5">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:getEntityByKeyRequest>
         <v1:entityKey>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <v11:applicationContext>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <v11:factoryClass>?</v11:factoryClass>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <v11:URL>?</v11:URL>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <v11:systemProperties>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <v11:property>
                     <v11:name>?</v11:name>
                     <v11:value>?</v11:value>
                  </v11:property>
               </v11:systemProperties>
            </v11:applicationContext>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <v11:applicationDN>?</v11:applicationDN>
            <v11:type>?</v11:type>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <v11:primaryKey>?</v11:primaryKey>
         </v1:entityKey>
         <v1:attrNames>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <v11:item>?</v11:item>
         </v1:attrNames>
      </v1:getEntityByKeyRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to send this form of XML:

```xml
<v1:getEntityByKeyRequest xmlns:v1="http://ossj.org/xml/Inventory/v1-2" xmlns:v12="http://ossj.org/xml/Common-CBEResource/v1-5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:v11="http://ossj.org/xml/Common/v1-5">
      <v1:entityKey xsi:type="v12:ResourceKey">
        <v11:type xsi:type="xs:string">resourceKey</v11:type>
        <v11:primaryKey xsi:type="xs:string">9135950291913240207</v11:primaryKey>
      </v1:entityKey>
<attrNames>
    <v1:item>9132441843113500508</v1:item>
</attrNames>
</v1:getEntityByKeyRequest>
```

But, using a generated java code, Web service recives XML with this form

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://ossj.org/xml/Inventory/v1-2" xmlns:v11="http://ossj.org/xml/Common/v1-5">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:getEntityByKeyRequest>
         <v1:entityKey>
            <v11:applicationContext>
               <v11:factoryClass></v11:factoryClass>
               <v11:URL></v11:URL>
               <v11:systemProperties>
                  <v11:property>
                     <v11:name></v11:name>
                     <v11:value></v11:value>
                  </v11:property>
               </v11:systemProperties>
            </v11:applicationContext>
            <v11:applicationDN></v11:applicationDN>
            <v11:type>resourceKey</v11:type>
            <v11:primaryKey>9135950291913240207</v11:primaryKey>
         </v1:entityKey>
         <v1:attrNames>
            <v11:item></v11:item>
         </v1:attrNames>
      </v1:getEntityByKeyRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So, how request to Web service using the java code with only 2 of the 4 parameters?

*P.S. Sorry for my bad English :)*